# Least squares not working for a set of y's

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, least-squares

I am trying to run a least square algorithm using `numpy` and is having trouble. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in the given code? When I set y to be `y = np.power(X, 1) + np.random.rand(20)*3` or some other reasonable function of x, everything is working fine. But for that particular y defined by those given y values, the plot I am getting is senseless.

Is this some kind of numerical problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

X = np.arange(1,21)
y = np.array([-0.00454712, -0.00457764, -0.0045166 , -0.00442505, -0.00427246,
       -0.00411987, -0.00378418, -0.003479  , -0.00314331, -0.00259399,
       -0.00213623, -0.00146484, -0.00082397, -0.00030518,  0.00027466,
        0.00076294,  0.00146484,  0.00192261,  0.00247192,  0.00314331])

#y = np.power(X, 1) + np.random.rand(20)*3

w = np.linalg.lstsq(X.reshape(20, 1), y)[0]

plt.plot(X, y, 'red')
plt.plot(X, X*w[0], 'blue')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you probably want `X.dot(w[0])`,

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried that but I am getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is a linear relationship between what you are fitting and the y variable data?

Using the code (`y = np.power(X, 1) + np.random.rand(20)*3`) from your example, you have a linear relationship built into the y variable itself (with some noise) which allows your plot to track relatively well with the linear equation.

```
X = np.arange(1,21)

#y = np.power(X, 1) + np.random.rand(20)*3

w = np.linalg.lstsq(X.reshape(20, 1), y)[0]

plt.plot(X, y, 'red')
plt.plot(X, X*w[0], 'blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

However, when you alternate to something like your y variable

```
    y = np.array([-0.00454712, -0.00457764, -0.0045166 , -0.00442505, -0.00427246,
       -0.00411987, -0.00378418, -0.003479  , -0.00314331, -0.00259399,
       -0.00213623, -0.00146484, -0.00082397, -0.00030518,  0.00027466,
        0.00076294,  0.00146484,  0.00192261,  0.00247192,  0.00314331])
```

You end up with something less easy to fit.

[image: Plot2]

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html), if you are attempting to something that fits this set of values, you will need to build in a constant component in which case `lstsq` does not do by default. 
The docs state for `lstsq`

> Return the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation.
>
> Solves the equation a x = b

If you really want to fit the data to a linear equation, running code like the below will give you something that almost matches your original data. However, the data behind this process seems to have polynomial/exponential driver which would make `polyfit` better.

```
X = np.arange(1,21)
y = np.array([-0.00454712, -0.00457764, -0.0045166 , -0.00442505, -0.00427246,
       -0.00411987, -0.00378418, -0.003479  , -0.00314331, -0.00259399,
       -0.00213623, -0.00146484, -0.00082397, -0.00030518,  0.00027466,
        0.00076294,  0.00146484,  0.00192261,  0.00247192,  0.00314331])

#y = np.power(X, 1) + np.random.rand(20)*3
X2 = np.vstack([X, np.ones(len(X))]).T
w = np.linalg.lstsq(X2, y)[0]


plt.plot(X, y, 'red')
plt.plot(X, X.dot(w[0])+w[1], 'blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot3]

Comment: Thank you. It did occur to me that the problem might be lack of a bias term but I dismissed it because as I understood it, even without the bias term the slope should work out; just that the line will be offseted by a certain amount. I guess that's not the way it works. This makes sense.